# Is there a performance improvement when using _ to ignore a parameter in Swift?

Tags: swift, performance

When creating a `UITableViewController`, sometimes I only need the `indexPath` in my function, is there a performance improvement when using `_` to ignore the `tableView` parameter?

*Ex:* using this:

```
override func tableView(_: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

instead of this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, this falls under the category "micro optimization". 
Even if there were a difference, it would probably be negligible 
compared to the rest of your program. And chances are great that the
compiler notices the unused parameter and optimizes the code
accordingly. You should decide what parameter name makes the most
sense in your situation.

In this particular case, it does not make any difference at all. 
How you name the (internal) method parameter affects only the compiling
phase, but does not change the generated code.

You can verify that easily
yourself. Create a source file "main.swift":

```
// main.swift
import Swift

func foo(str : String) -> Int {
    return 100
}

func bar(_ : String) -> Int {
    return 100
}

println(foo("a"))
println(bar("b"))
```

Now compile it and inspect the generated assembly code:

```
swiftc -O -emit-assembly main.swift
```

The assembly code for both methods is completely identical:

```
    .private_extern __TF4main3fooFSSSi
    .globl  __TF4main3fooFSSSi
    .align  4, 0x90
__TF4main3fooFSSSi:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movq    %rdx, %rdi
    callq   _swift_unknownRelease
    movl    $100, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq

    .private_extern __TF4main3barFSSSi
    .globl  __TF4main3barFSSSi
    .align  4, 0x90
__TF4main3barFSSSi:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movq    %rdx, %rdi
    callq   _swift_unknownRelease
    movl    $100, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```